# Why using UIImagePickerController like this?

Tags: ios, swift

In [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1) swift tutorial provided by apple, it has an example to select an image from the photo library. The code looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, // Question 1
                      UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    ...

    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        // Question 2
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Question 3
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have three questions about this code:

1. When do I need UIImagePickerControllerDelegate but not UINavigationControllerDelegate or vice versa?
2. Why does it create the imagePickerController as a local variable? Is a class instance variable a bad design in this case?
3. I tested the default behavior of imagePickerControllerDidCancel and it did dismiss the view controller. Then I looked up [its document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerControllerDidCancel:) which says the implementation is optional but expected. Why it is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Quite simply, the [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/) protocol is for responding to things that happen in the image picker. UIImagePickerController *also* requires its `delegate` to conform to [UINavigationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/), because an image picker *is* a (subclass of a) navigation controller. However, those methods are optional.
2. It wouldn't hurt, but there is just no need to save a reference to the image picker in an instance variable. The picker itself is passed in as the first parameter to the delegate methods. It will be automatically retained until it disappears.
3. You are expected to handle the `DidCancel` method and dismiss the controller because otherwise, the image picker would stay on screen!

   **Edit:** although it appears that nowadays, UIImagePickerController will automatically dismiss itself if you don't implement the delegate method.

   To test this, I just overrode `dismissViewControllerAnimated` to add a breakpoint:

   [image: breakpoint]

   Then you can see the following stack trace when you click the Cancel button:

   [image]

Comment: I tested the program without implementing the DidCancel, and it did dismiss the image picker. That's why I am wondering.

Comment: I see. I guess UIImagePickerController is trying to be nice, so you don't have to do any extra work :)

Comment: In the first question I asked when do I not need the navigation delegate if a class conforms the picker delegate. If that is always needed, isn't it make the code ugly and error-prone?

Comment: The UIImagePickerController `delegate` property is declared as `protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?` (because a UIImagePickerController is a subclass of UINavigationController, so this is overriding the superclass's `delegate`). This means the delegate must conform to both protocols. However, in both protocols all methods are optional, so you don't need to implement them. There is not much error-prone-ness here, it's just letting you know that your object is also a navigation controller's delegate.

Comment: where do you find the list in your Edit section?